# Canonical Console.WriteLine in LinqPad

Tags: linqpad

Linqpad's souped-up Console.WriteLine is awesome. However, how can I do a standard Console.WriteLine of an object?

Comment: if only this respected `Console` colors

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`Debug.WriteLine` will also do the trick.

Comment: if only this respected `Console` colors

Answer (score 13):

Huh, obvious now - put in an explicit ToString

```
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
x.Dump();
```

Which will use the LinqPad API to pretty format the output.

Comment: That's exactly what the OP wants to avoid in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add these methods to your "MyExtensions" file in the "My Queries" pane.  This way you can use .DumpToString instead of .Dump.  Maybe they should be renamed DumpDebug ...

```
// Write custom extension methods here. They will be available to all queries.
public static void DumpToString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    list.ToList().ForEach(x => Debug.WriteLine(x));
}

public static void DumpToString(this object o)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(o);
}

public static void DumpToString(this string o)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(o);
}
```